# how to generate 5 numbers from a list?

Tags: python, random, python-3.x

I'm trying to generate 5 numbers from a list but I don't know how I would do it?
I know how to use choice in the random module but I want it to choose multiple integers from a list like this:

```
randomnumbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Or do I have to do it manually, eg:

```
num1 = choice(randomnumbers)
num2 = choice(randomnumbers)
```

and so on..

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are duplicate choices allowed, or do you want five different numbers from the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`random.sample()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
from random import sample
picked = sample(randomnumbers, 5)
```

This picks 5 *different* numbers from the input list.

If duplicate numbers are allowed, a list comprehension will do with `random.choice` will do:

```
from random import choice
picked = [choice(randomnumbers) for _ in range(5)]
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> from random import sample, choice
>>> sample(randomnumbers, 5)
[1, 0, 9, 3, 2]
>>> [choice(randomnumbers) for _ in range(5)]
[1, 6, 5, 5, 0]
```